# What does it mean for a map taking a measure to an integral to be continuous?

Tags: integration, general-topology, measure-theory, continuity, weak-convergence

Suppose $\mathcal{M}$ is a set of probability measures. What does it mean to say that a mapping $\mu \rightarrow \int_{\mathbb{R}}f \ d\mu$ is continuous on $\mathcal{M}$? How could one prove that this mapping is continuous?

Would it suffice to show: $\int_{\mathbb{R} \setminus [-a,a]} f \ d\mu$ converges to $0$ uniformly in $\mu$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Any sources on this would be appreciated.

Comment: You would need some metric/topology on $\mathcal{M}$ for that to make sense. Your condition is only for fixed $\mu$, I don't see how it tells anything about continuity on $\mathcal{M}$. Unless this is a notation issue and actually $\mu$ is fixed and the function depends on $f$? This is weird. Where did you get that from? Some book?

Comment: I failed to mention: $\mathcal{M}$ is a set of probability measures. For simplicity assume that it is the set of all probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$ (In reality I am dealing with measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with given marginals). In this case does the standard weak convergence induce a topology on $\mathcal{M}$?

Comment: Right, so this changes a lot. There are multiple ways to define a distance between probability measures, see this: https://statweb.stanford.edu/~souravc/Lecture2.pdf Again, it's hard to tell without some context.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use your source